# My webpage disappears when the screen size is changed, is there anything wrong with my code to resize?

Tags: jquery, html

the webpage below slides from one page to another when the user clicks the tab on top, however i want it to resize and the screen blanks out when i try to resize my browser page.
I think there is a problem with my resize boxes code.
-html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Task 5 Report</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function resizeBoxes() {

    var browserWidth = $(window).width();
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();

    $('#main').css({
        width: browserWidth*4,
        height: browserHeight*1,
    });


    $('.box').css({
        width: browserWidth,
        height: browserHeight,
    });

}

resizeBoxes();

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeBoxes();
});


$('nav ul li a').click(function(){
    return false;
});

function goTo(horizontal,vertical) {

    var browserWidth = $(window).width();
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();

    $('#main').animate({
        marginLeft: '-'+browserWidth*horizontal,
        marginTop: '-'+browserHeight*vertical,
    }, 1000);

}


$('#link1 a').click(function(){
    goTo(0,0);
});


$('#link2 a').click(function(){
    goTo(1,0);
});

$('#link3 a').click(function(){
    goTo(2,0);
});

$('#link4 a').click(function(){
    goTo(3,0);
});



});
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">

<section id="box1" class="box">

<nav>
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a href="#">Server Side</a></li>
<li id="link4"><a href="#">Techical report</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>


    <h2>Kunal Matwani</h2>
    <h3>
This is a website with a portfolio of my work.<br> In this portfolio are the screenshots         depicting my work with the android prototype.<br>
    </h3>
</section>
<section id="box2" class="box">
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a href="#">Server Side</a></li>
<li id="link4"><a href="#">Techical report</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>


<h2>Big data</h3>
<p>
<ul class="contentul">
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
<li>List 3</li>
</ul>
</p>


</section>
<section id="box3" class="box">
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a href="#">Server Side</a></li>
<li id="link4"><a href="#">Techical report</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>

<h2>Server Side</h2>
<p>
This page contains all the information on the work done on the server side i.e MySql,Jetty etc. 
</p>

</section>
<section id="box4" class="box">
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a href="#">Server Side</a></li>
<li id="link4"><a href="#">Techical report</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>

<h2>Technical report</h2>
<p>
Attached is the technical report as required.
</p>

</section>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

-Css

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


/* 
 * These selection declarations have to be separate
 * No text-shadow: twitter.com/miketaylr/status/12228805301
 * Also: hot pink!
 */

::-moz-selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }


/* =============================================================================
   Links
   ========================================================================== */

a:hover, a:active { outline: 0; }

/*=========================================
    Main Styles
=========================================*/
body {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 54px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

h3 {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

p {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.contentul {
text-align: center;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
color: #ffffff;
}

/*=========================================
    Nav bar
=========================================*/
nav {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
height: 50px;
width: 25%;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
line-height: 50px;
display: block;
}

/*=========================================
    Nav links
=========================================*/
#link1 {
background: #1691BE;
}

#link2 {
background: #166BA2;
}

#link3 {
background: #1B3647;
}

#link4 {
background: #152836;
}





/*=========================================
    Styling each section
=========================================*/
.box {
float: left;
}

#box1 {
background: #1691BE;
}

#box2 {
background: #166BA2;
}

#box3 {
background: #1B3647;
}

#box4 {
background: #152836;
}
```

Comment: Put in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/227Rn/

Comment: What is the value you get for width() and height(). Did you check using the chrome debugger or using firebug

var browserWidth = $(window).width();
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();

Comment: I wouldn't use margins position content in this case... use `position: absolute` and `left: [number]px`, or even `scrollLeft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fw74k/1/ with the working version.

you have to remember the tab of where you are:

```
function goTo(horizontal,vertical) {

var browserWidth = $(window).width();
var browserHeight = $(window).height();

act[0] = horizontal;             //added this
act[1] = vertical;               //added this

$('#main').animate({
    marginLeft: '-'+browserWidth*horizontal,
    marginTop: '-'+browserHeight*vertical,
}, 1000);

}
```

and when you resize the window you must change the margin too:

```
$('#main').css({
    width: browserWidth*4,
    height: browserHeight*1,
    marginLeft: browserWidth*act[0]*-1,         //added this
    marginTop: browserHeight*act[1]*-1,         //added this
});
```

the `act = [0,0]` variable should defined just after the `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Thanks alot for that! I actually understood what you said as you explained it and I guess I won't be making that error again.